# Getting value using percent and rounding down

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a few values

```
Quantity  := 5;
Quantity2 := 8;
percent   :=50;
```

so i want

```
Percent of Quantity + Quantity 2
```

which would be like :  50% of 13 = 6.5

I done it like this

```
  HowMuchDamage := trunc(percent*(Quantity + Quantity2)/100);
```

How can i make it round up?
How can i make it round down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- [`Floor(X)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Floor) returns the highest integer less than or equal to X.
- [`Ceil(X)`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.Ceil) returns the lowest integer greater than or equal to X.